# What is the best way to solve this QP?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, least-squares, quadratic-programming

I have been studying the following optimization problem in $x_0, \dots, x_{n-1}$

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & \frac{1}{2} \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \left( x_{i-1} - x_i - y_i \right)^2\\ \text{subject to} & x_j \in [-\alpha_j, \alpha_j]\end{array}$$

where $y_1, \dots, y_n$ and $\alpha_0, \dots, \alpha_{n-1} \geq 0$ are constants.

What is the best way to solve this QP? Best in terms of computation effort (speed and memory requirements).

Thanks!

Comment: For numerical algorithm, I think interior points is a good numerical algorithm.

Comment: small typo: $\{y_i\} = \{y_1, y_2,...,y_{n-1}\}$

Comment: $y_n$ is not used.

Answer (score 1):

This is a **constrained least-squares** problem that can be written in the form

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & \| \mathrm A \mathrm x - \mathrm b \|_2^2\\ \text{subject to} & -\mathrm c \leq \mathrm x \leq \mathrm c\end{array}$$

where $\mathrm c > 0_n$ and $\rm A$ is the following $(n-1) \times n$ matrix

$$\mathrm A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & -1 & & & \\ & 1 & -1 & & \\ & & \ddots & \ddots & \\ & & & 1 & -1\end{bmatrix}$$

Since this is a **fat** matrix, the linear system $\mathrm A \mathrm x = \mathrm b$ is underdetermined. Since $\rm A$ has full row rank, $\mathrm A \mathrm A^\top$ is invertible and, thus, the **least-norm** solution is

$$\mathrm x_{\text{LN}} := \mathrm A^\top \left( \mathrm A \mathrm A^\top \right)^{-1} \mathrm b$$

Since $\rm A 1_n = 0_{n-1}$, the $1$-dimensional null space is spanned by $1_n$. Thus, the solution set is the **line**

$$\left\{ \color{blue}{\mathrm x_{\text{LN}} + t 1_n} \mid t \in \mathbb R \right\}$$

Does this line intersect the **feasible region**? If $-\mathrm c \leq \mathrm x_{\text{LN}} \leq \mathrm c$, we can immediately conclude that the line does indeed intersect the feasible region. If not, we then have $n$ inequalities in parameter $t$

$$-\mathrm c \leq \mathrm x_{\text{LN}} + t 1_n \leq \mathrm c$$

If the line does intersect the feasible region, then the minimum of the original quadratic program is *zero*. If the line does **not** intersect the feasible region, then the minimum is *positive*. In this case, we can use, say, MATLAB's [lsqlin](https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/lsqlin.html) to solve the quadratic program numerically.

Comment: Note that $\rm A$ is the *oriented* incidence matrix of a [linear graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_graph) on $n$ nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Alternating direction method of multipliers (ADMM) should solve this problem with linear convergence rate (for a given accuracy).

Define $z_i=x_i+\alpha_i$, $z_{i+n}=-x_i+\alpha_i$, where $z_i\geq0$ and a matrix $A\in\mathbb{R}^{2n\times n}$ such that $z=Ax$. So your problem has the following form:

\begin{equation}
min_{x\in\mathbb{R}^n \\ z\in\mathbb{R}^{2n} \\ z=Ax}\sum_i(x_{i-1}-x_{i}-y_i)^2+\delta_{\mathbb{R}_+^{2n}}(z)
\end{equation}

and apply ADMM (you can find here https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/papers/pdf/prox_algs.pdf more details).

Comment: From a numerical point of view, I think an interior point method would be much faster than ADMM.